# angucomplete Initial Value doesn't display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete

I'm trying to set an initial value in my angucomplete directive but it doesn't work, I've tried everything but no success, am I doing it wrong?

My autocomplete works fine, no problem, only the initial-value that I'm trying to set doesn't work. It just stays blank. Am I missing something?

Im using this directive - [Link](https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete)

```
<angucomplete 
    maxlength="50"
    pause="100" 
    selectedobject="flight_details.operating_airline" 
    localdata="airlines" 
    searchfields="label" 
    titlefield="label" 
    minlength="1" 
    inputclass="form-control form-control-small" 
    matchclass="highlight" 
    name="operating_airline"
    initial-value="Show Something"
    id="operating_airline"/>
```

Comment: Any feedback Pedro?

Comment: Hello, i leave this directive and started using angucomplete-alt

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the [documentation](https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete) there is no attribute `initial-value` in angucomplete. You can't achieve this with angucomplete.